# Conditional updating: Update only if value is None or 'null' or key doesn't exist

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to use conditionals such as $set to do more advanced updating. This is what I'm trying to do in pseudo code:

```
# new data to use in a possible update
newData = { 'emailAddress' : $usersEmailAddress,
            'keyA' : 'valueA', 
            'keyB' : None,
            'keyC' : '<null>' }

self.request.root.db.users.update(
                { 'emailAddress' : newData['emailAddress'] },
                { '$set': { 
                          "Here, loop through all newData keys/values and if 
                          notNull(newData[key]) == True and is different than the 
                          corresponding key/value in the user 
                          document (or if user document doesn't have that key) 
                          than update with newData key/value"
                          } }, upsert = False, safe = True )

# The result should be that if the value of keyA (and ONLY key A because the 
#  others are null) is different in the user document
#  than in newData, than the user document should be updated with the new value.



# function to catch any possible None value or equivalent string
def notNull(valueToCheck):
    if thingToCheck and thingToCheck != "null" and thingToCheck != 'nil' and thingToCheck != '<null>' and thingToCheck != '' and thingToCheck != ' ':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

What's the most efficient way of doing this? Because currently I'm having to pull the entire document with find_one and, I'm told, thats rather expensive. Is there a way to do this with just $set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, MongoDB does not support this feature. You can either, as you say, retrieve the document, analyze it in your client-side code, and issue an update based on its contents, or you could issue a series of updates like:

```
db.users.update({
    'emailAddress': newData['emailAddress'],
    '$or': [
        { 'keyA': { '$exists': false } },
        { 'keyA': None } ] }
    ]
}, {
    '$set': { 'keyA': newData['keyA'] }
})
```

The former will be more efficient, of course, since it's a single fetch and a single update. But consider whether you need to guard against multiple MongoDB clients simultaneously fetching and updating the same document.